# Magento2: How to insert dynamic generated coupon code in email templates

Tags: magento2, email-templates

Requirement: every time a customer place an order, a free shipping coupon will be sent which can only be used once.

So I need to insert the dynamic coupon code just like gift card code and abandoned cart rule coupon on normal email template.

Appreciate for any comment and solution.

Answer (score 4):

Yes,it is possible.

- Create A cart rules from `admin>Marketing>Cart Rules`.
- Create a rules which *will create dynamic coupon by* selecting '**Use
  Auto Generation**' for create multiple couple coupons.

**During Creation setting should be :**

[image]

Now,Add ***custom data in order email  template*** in Magento 2 and *create a coupon of the rule*,you should fire run observer at event `email_order_set_template_vars_before`.

> $this->eventManager->dispatch(
>               'email_order_set_template_vars_before',
>               ['sender' => $this, 'transport' => $transport]
>           );

So, at this event you can add ***new parameter via  transport to template*** means you can create coupon and send to email.

**Just like:**
**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="email_order_set_template_vars_before">
        <observer name="add_Custom_variable_to_Order" 
            instance="[Vendor]\[ModuleName]\Observer\ObserverforAddCustomVariable" />
    </event>
</config>
```

And at observer will create coupon and send to to email:

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[ModuleName]\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;

class ObserverforAddCustomVariable implements ObserverInterface
{

    protected $ruleFactory;
    protected $massgenerator;
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(\Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory $ruleFactory,\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon\Massgenerator $massgenerator, \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger ) {
        $this->ruleFactory= $ruleFactory;
        $this->massgenerator = $massgenerator;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action $controller */
        $transport = $observer->getTransport();
        $couponCode = $this->createOneCoupon();
        if($couponCode){
            $transport['free-coupon'] = $couponCode;
        }
    }
    protected function createOneCoupon()
    {
        $ruleModel = $this->ruleFactory->create();
        $ruleModel->load({RulesID});
         try {
                $data = array(
                        'rule_id' => 1,
                        'qty' => 1,
                        'length' => '12',
                        'format' => 'alphanum',
                        'prefix' => 'free-shipping',
                        'suffix' => '',
                        'dash'=>0
                        );


                $generator = $this->massgenerator;
                if (!$generator->validateData($data)) {
                   return false;
                } else {
                    $generator->setData($data);
                    $generator->generatePool();
                    $generated = $generator->getGeneratedCount();
                    $codes = $generator->getGeneratedCodes();
                    return $codes[0];

                }
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->logger->critical($e);
                return false;
            } catch (\Exception $e) {

                $this->logger->critical($e);
                return false;
            }
    }

}
```

**At the email template , you can get this custom variables free-coupon using  `{{var free-coupon|raw}}.`**

[how to add custom data in order email in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163916/how-to-add-custom-data-in-order-email-in-magento-2)

Comment: Can you post event name for newsletter subscription email?

Answer (score 0):

Working fine.Thanks a lot.Only issue with `object manager object`.

Just added `$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();`

And working fine.

Answer (score 0):

We should not use Object manager to create object.

I did some miner changes in existing code and working fine.
 protected $ruleFactory;
    protected $massGenerator;

```
public function __construct(

\Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory $ruleFactory,
\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon\Massgenerator  $massGenerator

    )
{

$this->rulesFactory = $ruleFactory;
$this->massGenerator = $massGenerator;

}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
  /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action $controller */
    $transport = $observer->getTransport();
    $couponCode = $this->createOneCoupon();
    if($couponCode){
        $transport['couponcode'] = $couponCode;
    }

}  


protected function createOneCoupon()
{

     try {
            $data = array(
                    'rule_id' => 4,
                    'qty' => 1,
                    'length' => '12',
                    'format' => 'alphanum',
                    'prefix' => '',
                    'suffix' => '',
                    'dash'=>0
                    );


            if (!$this->massGenerator->validateData($data)) {
               return false;
            } else {
                $this->massGenerator->setData($data);
                $this->massGenerator->generatePool();
                $generated = $this->massGenerator->getGeneratedCount();
                $codes = $this->massGenerator->getGeneratedCodes();
                return $codes[0];

            }
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e);
            return false;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {

            $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e);
            return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: Hello !! I suggest you to edit and update your code in your first answer instead of adding new/another answer for same question