# I want to add delivery date in order email template in Magento-2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1, order-email, delivery-date

I want to show delivery date in order-email template.I want to show in delivery date (today date + 10 day). How can I achieve that?

Comment: anybody help me?

Comment: Please review this URL: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163916/how-to-add-custom-data-in-order-email-in-magento-2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this you need to create a simple module say **Mago_Delivery**. Create following files

> app/code/Mago/Delivery/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Mago_Delivery',
__DIR__
);
```

> app/code/Mago/Delivery/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Mago_Delivery" setup_version="1.0.1">
   </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/Mago/Delivery/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order" type="Mago\Delivery\Model\Rewrite\Order" />
</config>
```

> app/code/Mago/Delivery/Model/Rewrite/Order.php

```
<?php

namespace Mago\Delivery\Model\Rewrite;

class Order extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
{

    public function getDeliveryDate()
    {
        $orderDate = $this->getCreatedAt(); //ORDER CREATED DATE
        return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($orderDate. ' + 10 days'));
    }

}
```

Finally in your email template you can get this date by:

**{{var order.getDeliveryDate()}}**

**Note:** I have created `getDeliveryDate()` function in general way, You can change it as per your requirement.

Hope above will help!

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Worked perfectly in M2.3.5.

Comment: @Webninja, Most welcome :)

Comment: Did not work for me in Magento ver. 2.3.6

Comment: @pawan, How can we change this to work with the new email variables of Magento? Because {{var order.getDeliveryDate()}} does not work anymore at the moment

Answer (score 1):

In order to show delivery date in order Email, you have pass variables in your email function.

First, we need to get a delivery date in (today date + 10 days) format so for this you have to define the date in a construct like:

```
protected $date;

public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->date = $date;
    ....
}

parent::__construct($date);

$date = $this->date->gmtDate();

//////In Execute Function//////
$date = $this->date->gmtDate();

$DeliveryDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+10 day', strtotime($date)));
```

$DeliveryDate will return (today date+10) date.

Pass $DeliveryDate variable in your Email function and use it in your email template.

Comment: How to use this codes? Can you eloborate your answer please,it will be helpful to me and fellow newbies,In  ..vendor\magento\module-sales\Model\order.php created construct,where to edit execute function,which file..?