# how to show order delivery date in order confirmation email in magento2.1.7

Tags: magento2

How to show order delivery date in new order confirmation email in magento2.1.7
plz someone guide me on this
thanks in advance..
i have referred this link [I want to add delivery date in order email template in Magento-2.1?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/241403/i-want-to-add-delivery-date-in-order-email-template-in-magento-2-1) but could not achieve my requirement

Comment: what issue you are getting in referred link ?

Comment: im not getting any issues..

Comment: in question you mention that you refereed a link and not achieve goal !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i achieved my requirement..now its working fine..
The path to apply this code is vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/order_new.html for registered user and for guest user the path is vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/order_new_guest.html

```
    <td class="method-info">
                     {{depend shipping_arrival_date}}
                        <h3>{{trans "Order Delivery Date"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var shipping_arrival_date}}</p>
                    {{/depend}}

                </td>
                {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}

    </tr>
```