# Magento 2.3 - Transactional email remove time from order date

Tags: magento2.3, transactional-mail, date

How can we remove the time in the order created date inside the transactional email?

We now load it like this; `{{var created_at_formatted}}` and displayed as: `9 apr. 2020 11:17:59`

We want to remove the time and change the format to 9 April 2020.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `{{trans '%created_at' created_at=$order.getCreatedAtFormatted(3)}}`

All possible parameter of getCreatedAtFormatted() are :

```
/* date/time format types */
const NONE = -1;
const FULL = 0;
const LONG = 1;
const MEDIUM = 2;
const SHORT = 3;
```

If it doesn't work then override method getCreatedAtFormatted($format) from  vendor\magento\modules-sales\model\Order.php ; in your custom module and set $format to 0 when calling it in your mail template.

```
public function getCreatedAtFormatted($format)
{
return $this->timezone->formatDateTime(
    new \DateTime($this->getCreatedAt()),
    $format,
    $format,
    $this->localeResolver->getDefaultLocale(),
    $this->timezone->getConfigTimezone('store', $this->getStore()),
    'd M Y' // <-------------------- add this   
);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems that `{{trans '%created_at' created_at=$order.getCreatedAtFormatted(3)}}` got the output; `09-04-2020 11:17` Still the time displayed. Any other solutions instead of changing the `Order.php` file?

Comment: No i think the only way is to change this method or the better soluction is to create other method and call it in mail template, like in this post  https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/241626/88489

Comment: Thanks! That works perfect.