# How to display estimated delivery date in order email template in Magento-2.3.5

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, email-templates, order-email

How to display estimated delivery date in order email template in Magento-2.3.5

Exp: "Wed, December 2nd, 2020 - Fri, December 4th, 2020" like this

Comment: try https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/241403/i-want-to-add-delivery-date-in-order-email-template-in-magento-2-1/241626#241626

Comment: I want to do like this estimated delivery:
"Wed, December 2nd, 2020 - Fri, December 4th, 2020"  How to do