# handle conflicts when override Order Sender class in magento 2

Tags: magento2, email, overrides, sales-order, conflict

I am overriding OrderSender class for add custom variable in order confirmation mail. This variable's value is dynamic.

but this file conflicts and give an error like

> "Type Error occurred when creating object:
>   Magento\Sales\Model\OrderNotifier".

I want to add a custom variable in the order confirmation mail.

I override the class using di.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender" />
 </config>
```

Any solution is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: email_order_set_template_vars_before event for Add custom data in order email

Comment: you can set custom data using event

Comment: I tried event and observer also but it does not work for me can you please post the code for me.

Comment: please check my answer

Comment: I have to override order_new.html file in my custom module or not?

Comment: you can set varibale using admin backend  Marketing -> Email Templates ->order email

Comment: no i think its not a necessary to override that file

Comment: ok, so this two files I have to put n my module and set variable through the admin panel and the value of my variable will be set right?

Comment: yes bro may be :)

Comment: Thanks brother it works for me. now please tell me can i get custom collection in observer?

Comment: custom collection means ???

Comment: custom collection means data of table same as like product collection and i also want session data so it is possible to get all that details in observer?

Comment: yes you can....

Comment: ok brother, you are awesome man. it was a great conversation with you. Thanks for your help!

Comment: most welcome.. happy coding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **event.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="email_order_set_template_vars_before">
        <observer name="add_Custom_variable_to_Order" 
            instance="[Vendor]\[ModuleName]\Observer\ObserverforAddCustomVariable" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> **Observer file:**

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[ModuleName]\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class ObserverforAddCustomVariable implements ObserverInterface
{

    public function __construct(
    ) {
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action $controller */
        $transport = $observer->getTransport();
        $transport['CustomVariable1'] = 'Your Value1 ';
        $transport['CustomVariable2'] = 'Your Value2';
    }
}
```

**At the email template , you can get this custom variables CustomVariable1,CustomVariable2 using  {{var CustomVariable1|raw}},{{var CustomVariable2|raw}}**

[Reference Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/163950/72911)