# Order success mail is not coming with dynamic value in magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, order-email, magento2.3.2

I've override the default.phtml file in for order success mail for dynamic value of storename. The below code will work when we send the order from admin panel but same code is not working when we placed the order the store name is missing on the mail.

Please help where i'm doing mistake.

File location -

> /home/top10/public_html/app/design/frontend/Magento/Vendorname/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml

```
    <?php

/** @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\DefaultItems */

/** @var $_item \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item */
$_item = $block->getItem();
$_order = $_item->getOrder();
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();


    if ($_order->getShippingMethod() == 'customerpickup_customerpickup') {

        $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $connection = $resource->getConnection();
        $order_id = $_order->getIncrementId();
        $sql = "SELECT `name` FROM `stores` WHERE `store_id` = (select store_id from clickncollect where order_id = '".$order_id."')";
        $result=$connection->fetchOne($sql);
        $store_name = "Click and Collect From ".$result;
    }else{
        $store_name = "";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: remove `)`  on this line ` $store_name = "Click and Collect From ".$result);`

Comment: yes removed but not working

Comment: In else part can you give some static text and check it like `else{
     $store_name = "test";
}`

Comment: else part is working fine if shipping method is different

Comment: store name is not a problem,  then  check within your your if condition  and  check     with your  query result.

Comment: if i send the order mail from back end it is working but when i placed the order it doesn't work.

Comment: `print_r($result)` or `var_dump($result)`  check  that first  if you  get a value

Comment: var_dump value is false but i print query the query is working fine in sql

Comment: please share your  result as screenshot

Comment: In the `if condition`  you can check  with the static text of store name

Comment: You should't use sql query directly in magento. Try this method - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163916/magento-2-how-to-add-custom-data-in-order-email#163950

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/IC4DbxO.png  if shipping method is click and collect it coming into if condition that is right.

Comment: i think  `$store_name = "Click and Collect From ".$result;`   you are not getting any  value in the $result

Comment: but if hit from backend same code will work

Comment: can you please share a screenshot for print_r($result)

Comment: Atharva string(7) - var_dum($result);

Answer (score 0):

Get store name from order

```
$store_name = $_order->getStore()->getName();
if($store_name){
   $store_name= "Click and Collect From ".$store_name;
}
```

Comment: I want store name from my custom table 'store'

Comment: print $sql in log and run in your DB / compare it with admin order and check what is missing there

Comment: if i send mail from admin panel it will work. when i placed that only time store name not coming

Comment: update question with $sql in both case it will help better to solve it