# Magento 2: Show Custom fields in checkout form, information in Order email

Tags: magento2

We have added a plugin to add extra custom fields in checkout page of magento2 using this plugin. 
https://github.com/sbodak/magento2-checkout-custom-form

It save this information in Order, and this infomation can be seen if we open order in backend.
[image]

You can also check the fields of this plugin in checkout page in front end here.
[image]

And here is the code of plugin which is used to show this order fields in Backend.
[image]

Now i want to show this information in Order email which is sent to customer automatically after each order. Here is the screen shot of that email template in Marketing->Email Templates.
Here you can see in template code there are variables to show different order information. Can i use some variable here which will show this new custome fields of Delivery Date and Delivery Time etc in email templetes?
[image]

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163916/magento-2-how-to-add-custom-data-in-order-email Check this question and solution

Answer (score 0):

Add a new module to your mangento installation.
in my case Badi\Customvariable
add etc/events.xml and add the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="email_order_set_template_vars_before">
        <observer name="badi_add_custom_variable_to_Order" instance="Badi\Customvariable\Observer\ObserverforAddCustomVariable" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Now add Observer/ ObserverforAddCustomVariable.php and add the following code

```
<?php
    namespace Badi\Customvariable\Observer;
    use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    class ObserverforAddCustomVariable implements ObserverInterface
    {
        protected $customerRepository;
        public function __construct(
            CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
        ) {
            $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        }
        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
        {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action $controller */
            $transport = $observer->getEvent()->getTransport();
            if($transport->getOrder() != null)
            {
                $transport['deliverydate'] = $transport->getOrder()->getCheckoutDeliveryDate(); 
                $transport['deliverytime'] = $transport->getOrder()->getCheckoutDeliveryTime();  
            }
        }
    }
```