# Order email getShippingDescription - remove method name

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, email-templates, order-email

In magento configuration, I have set Flat Rate like this:

[image]

Yet in order confirmation email, `{{var order.getShippingDescription()}}` returns 
**Flat Rate - Delivery**

I'd like to remove Flat Rate, and have just **Delivery** displayed.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

`Flat Rate - Delivery` is coming from the database column `shipping_description`  of sales_order table.

If you want to changes `Flat Rate - Delivery` text only for order confirmation mail then best of idea add a new parameter to order confirmation email using event `email_order_set_template_vars_before` and on this parameter will have to do a string replace on `shipping_description` field And then order on email template access the new parameter.

See https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/163950/4564

First,Read the dev docs article on [Events and observers](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html)

1 .**Create `events.xml` at your module means `app/code/{VendorName}/{Modulename}/etc`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="email_order_set_template_vars_before">
        <observer name="changes_shippig_descitption_text" 
            instance="{VendorName}\{Modulename}\Observer\ChangesShippingText" />
    </event>
</config>
```

2 .**Add new parameter named `new_shippping_desc`  to  email using `transportObject`**

```
<?php 
namespace {VendorName}\{Modulename}\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ChangesShippingText implements ObserverInterface
{

  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {
     $transport = $observer->getTransportObject();
     $order = $transport->getData('order');
     $shippingDes = $order->getShippingDescription();
     $trimDescription = str_replace("Flat Rate -","",$shippingDes);
     $transport->setData('new_shippping_desc',$trimDescription);
  }
}
```

3. After on order_email template changes the code `{{var order.getShippingDescription()}}` to `{{var new_shippping_desc}}

Comment: I don't understand the details of this, please post the code as a answer

Comment: Code is attach on the post

Comment: observer file should be called `ChangesShippingText.php` and should be placed in directory `app/code/{VendorName}/{Modulename}/Observer`?

Comment: yes, right.`app/code/{VendorName}/{Modulename}/Observer`

Comment: have you tested your solution? It currently breaks email sending. Please confirm that `app/code/{VendorName}/{Modulename}/Observer/ChangesShippingText.php` is correct